# Why are these sums equal?

Tags: summation, pi

I've been looking at some pretty cool proofs of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$ recently, and the one proof that was the easiest to understand for me was how Euler originally presented it, by [finding and manipulating](http://ptrow.com/articles/Infinite_Series_Sept_07.htm) the infinite series for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Through the the wild and mostly ridiculous thought process that leads me to most of my cooler mathematical experiments, I thought: "What if I made an infinite sum out of that infinite series?" ***Infinitiception***. So, I ended up researching the sum in question:
$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\;$$

and it turns out it is well known as $\pi$! This was awesome. I love pi, and while the connection here is quite obvious, it is still fun to see it pop up everywhere. But then, through some playing around, I found this:

$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\;= \sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{2}=\pi\;$$
This simply doesn't seem possible to me. How can a series equal itself squared? $\sin^2 \neq \sin$, and obviously $x^2 \neq x$, so how can this be true?  Is it even true? I would appreciate an explanation with as little calculus as possible, unless it is needed or more elegant with calculus. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Infinite sum of infinite series"? There are double series: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html

Comment: You didn't square the whole series, you squared each of the terms individually. Of course these are different series; in the first series you add some positive terms to the sum, then some negative terms, then some positive terms, rinse and repeat; in the second series you are always adding positive terms. It's interesting but not shocking that the two series have the same limit; there are infinitely many series that all converge to the same limit as these two. (You could say the same about any other limit  you might want.)

Comment: Just as a word of caution, be careful with infinite series; some very strange stuff happens, very often. No answer from me [it's equally puzzling to me], but just an observation: Equally cool IMO is that $∫_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = π$

Comment: To make this work, incidentally, you have to substitute $1$ for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x = 0$; that is the limit as $x\to0$, so it's reasonable, but I'm not sure it's OK to just assume that without mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no paradox here. It's quite possible for the sum of a bunch of numbers to equal the sum of the squares of those numbers. This happens even in finite sums:
$$
\frac13+\frac13+\frac43=\bigg(\frac13\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac13\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac43\bigg)^2
$$
$$
-\frac13+\frac12+c=\bigg({-}\frac13\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac12\bigg)^2+c^2 \text{ for either } c = \frac{3\pm\sqrt2}6.
$$

Comment: It even happens for even “more finite” sums: $1=1^2$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^2$

Answer (score 0):

@GregMartin Gives a good example above, but we could use intuition to show that this is possible. Remember that if we have a number greater than $0$ but less than $1$ then we have that this number squared is less than itself. i.e.: $$0<x<1\implies x^2<x$$Now we have that $$\bigg|\frac{\sin x}x\bigg|\ge\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2$$So you could think of the sum of $\frac{\sin x}x$ as an alternating series, while the sum of its squares gives positive terms but with less magnitude.